# parse xml image for iOS

Tags: xml, parsing

I'm looking for more than a week now functional code to read image link xml. it would be great to help me because I really need

Can you help me please?

Davy

Comment: From which kind of xml files are you talking? Could you add an example? Please also add the ios tag.